# Memory allocation for mediumtext field with limit set at a lesser value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, memory-management

In my rails migration, one of the field is defined as

```
t.text :message, limit: 8.megabytes - 1
```

Mysql maps this field to mediumtext datatype. But mediumtext can store data upto 16megabytes.

My question is, how does mysql handle this internally? How much memory is allocated for my message field, 8megabytes or 16megabytes? Does it actually save memory or is it the same if I write my migration for this field as

```
t.text :message, limit: 16.megabytes - 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MEDIUMTEXT just needs as much space as the actual text that is stored plus a few bytes for administration. So for the database size this doesn't matter.

The difference is in what rails will allow you to store in there. In the first version it will only allow you to store 8 megabytes and in the second version 16, even though the database will always allow 16.

This could create problems if you write something in the filed externally. If it is too long, rails will complain when you try to read and modify it.